# Как найти объект в объекте?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Допустим, у нас есть некий объект. Его структуру и то, что внутри, мы не знаем, но знаем, что там должен быть, например, объект `innerObject`, который может находится где угодно внутри. Вот пример объекта:

```
var someObj1 = {
    io1: {sIo1:{ssIo01:'что-то'}}
    oi2: {
        sIo1:{
            innerObject: {/*внутренности объекта*/}
        }
    }
}
```

И структура этого объекта и то, где будет находиться наш `innerObject`, нам не известно. Известно еще то, что `innerObject` находится *НЕ* в массиве.
**Как** найти в некотором объекте, объект `innerObject`?

**PS**:
Без использования каких-либо библиотек.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function checkInObject( obj, name ) {
  var res = null;
  for( var i in obj ) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      if(i === name) {
        res = obj[i];
        break;
      }
      if(obj[i] && obj[i].constructor === Object) {
        var check = checkInObject( obj[i], name );
        if( check ) {
          res = check;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}

var someObj1 = {
  io1: {sIo1:{ssIo01:'что-то'}},
  oi2: {
    sIo1:{
      innerObject: { test : "done" }
    }
  }
}

console.log(checkInObject( someObj1, 'innerObject' ).test); // -> done
```

Comment: а можно поитересоваться, почему вы используете `break;`, если можно использовать `return`, или в js если принципиальные различия между этими подходами?

Comment: Это хороший тон написания функции (не только в javascript, а вообще), чтобы во всей функции всегда был return и только в одном месте.

Comment: А привык я так писать после того как поработал месяц в команде, где обязательным требованием является валидность JSLint =)

Comment: Спасибо, возьму на заметку.
>валидность JSLint

ну тогда в вашем коде `"use strict"` не хватает=)

Comment: @Spectre - так если добавить все чисто будет, не писал дабы не задавали лишних вопросов. И он тут не нужен =)

Comment: Спасибо, вы на половину ответили на мой предыдущий вопрос про гугло-карты:) Очень красиво и коротко! Прям гениально!